# print functionality is not working in react-native webview in ios

Tags: react-native, expo

The print functionality that we use in react-native web-view is not working.
It works in browser like chrome but is not working for web-view.On clicking print button it doesn't perform its function

```js
<WebView ref={WEBVIEW_REF} 
style={ styles.wview } 
source={{ uri: url }} 
style = {{marginTop:20}} 
key={this.state.key} 
onNavigationStateChange={this._onNavigationStateChange.bind(this)} startInLoadingState={true} />
```

Comment: Please provide the code with the problem.

Comment: <WebView ref={WEBVIEW_REF} style={ styles.wview }  source={{ uri: url }}
        style = {{marginTop:20}} key={this.state.key} onNavigationStateChange={this._onNavigationStateChange.bind(this)}
        startInLoadingState={true}
        
        />

Comment: @hongdevelop please help me

Comment: Does this code work on Android but not on iOS?

Comment: code is working fine

Comment: Inside the webview print button is nothing happened

Comment: Print button? Where is the print button?

Comment: In http://posdemo.cybersyskw.com
login with demo >> then click the first item on the dropdown >> click on the top left side >>> click on sales >> then seach the panadol in the search bar >> then complete sales >> then warning popup >>> then click ok button >> showing print sheet .



firstly,Please follow the steps in chrome its working fine
But inside the webview print sheet is not showing

Comment: @hongdevelop please help me